# ECDH VS. DH benchmarking in JAVA

Tags: java, cryptography, diffie-hellman

This questions was previously posted on [crypto.exchange](https://crypto.stackexchange.com/questions/6202/ecdh-vs-dh-benchmarking-in-java), however since my problem still remain i thought perhaps this could be more of a programming detail that i might have overlooked and not something theoretical.

So basically my problem is the odd result i get when measuring the time it takes to generate a ECDH key in java vs. the time it takes to generate a DH key.

I compare the time it takes to generate:

- 192bit ECDH-key to a 512bit DH-key
- 224bit ECDH-key to a 1024 DH-key

Now I expected the ECDH key pair generation to beat regular DH keys due to difference in key size, however that is not the case when I do it. Perhaps I'm measuring this wrong or is there another explanation.

```
    public void generateKeyPair() {

    try {

        keyfactory = KeyFactory.getInstance("ECDH");

        keyPairGenerator = KeyPairGenerator.getInstance("ECDH", "BC");

        //NIST EC-Curve P-224"
        org.bouncycastle.jce.spec.ECParameterSpec ecSpec = ECNamedCurveTable.getParameterSpec(EllipticCurveDiffieHellman.curveNames.get(new Integer(224)));

        keyPairGenerator.initialize(ecSpec, new SecureRandom());

    int num = 10;

        /* Warm up */
        for (int wRound = 0; wRound < 200; wRound++) {
            keyPairGenerator.generateKeyPair(); 
        }

        /*
         * Finding the right number of iterations such that we iterate for
         * at least 2s
         */
        for (;;) {

            long begin = System.currentTimeMillis();

            for (int i = 0; i < num; i++) {

                keypair = keyPairGenerator.generateKeyPair();
            }

            long end = System.currentTimeMillis();

            long time = end - begin;

            if (time >= 2000) {
                System.out.printf("Average keygen time: %.2f ms\n",
                        (double) time / num);
                break;
            }

            num *= 2;
        }

    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}
```

Comment: Uh, what was wrong with Pornins answer? It does seem to include quite a bit on Java specific issues?

Comment: Well Pornins answer was indeed enlightning however did not solve the problem, i.e. DH keypair generation (1024 bit) remains faster than ECDH keypair generation (NIST P-224 curve). I mean ECDH should be faster instead average key generation takes 7 ms compared to DH 3 ms..

Comment: Why do you insist that ECDH key generation should be faster? ECDH will be faster or much much faster for *comparable security* operands. Thus 512-bit DH should be compared to 100-bit ECDH (but don't bother for such small sizes) and 1024-bit DH should be compared to 128-bit ECDH. P-224 should be benchmarked against DH with a 2700-bit prime, not a 1024 bit prime.

Comment: @GregS: I see if that is the case then it isn't surprising ECDH is slower. Could you perhaps point me to a source that verifies your claim? :)

Comment: @me_L_coding: I got all my numbers from [keylength.com](http://www.keylength.com/)